# ionic app runs on iOS 10.1 emulator perfectly, but errors when deployed to a device

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ipa

I have an ionic application that i have been deploying to google play and itunes store successfully. **All the current functionality works great on all android devices tested.**

For iOS, I am able to see all the functionality working great using

```
ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone-6-Plus"
```

**(Or any target, really!)**

When I build an ipa following the normal steps on https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html ... and upload the ipa to testobject.com and I cannot get the same successes.

For iOS platform 8.0, 8.1, and 8.2 the app will load, but some functionality doesn't work.

For iOS platform 8.3 - 10.1 the app either loads a blank white page, or a red page with an error stack I cannot read.

What are the normal debugging steps for this type of scenario? Like i said i can build to an emulator just fine...

Here is my plugin list.

```
kirbsah$ ionic plugins list
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.1 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.3 "SocialSharing"
ionic-plugin-deploy 0.6.5 "IonicDeploy"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.1 "PushPlugin"
```

Here is my ionic information

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.12 
OS: Mac OS X Sierra
Node Version: v7.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

Any help or direction appreciated. I would assume the problem is somewhere in my xcode build process... but i'm just following documentation.

Comment: I just have to say this is how it is ... you solved one problem(multiplatfom framework, write once and run enywhere e.t.c) and created other(no real comunity of ios users, not really tested under so many situations that can arise, not really native coding, because you just skipped it)...

Comment: Yea. I can understand that. If you were in this situation.. how would you break it down? Where would you start?   I think the biggest question is.. how does my code work at all in an emulator?

Comment: `Edit Scheme` change debug to release to test it. You should test both 8.1 and 10.1. Go to download the 8.1 emulator.

Comment: @Kirby You can try to get logs from TestObject. 
https://testobject.com/, paste logs here.

Comment: I don't think it would be a gamechanger but I suggest to use Node LTS version (current is V6.9.2). I see you are developing for Ionic1, aren't you? You don't have an iOS device to connect it to Xcode and see debug console?